# Enable ssh in emergency mode for centos 9

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, centos, grub

I'm trying make a backup system for my Centos Stream 9 headless server by installing a cloned system disk on a newer machine.

No surprise, the newer machine booted into emergency mode (hardware different).

As every one know, There are very limited functions are available in emergency mode,

I can enable network by using:

```
ip link 
ip link set dev enp1s0 up 
ip addr add 10.0.1.89/24 dev enp1s0
ip route add default via 10.0.1.1
```

then NIC status is up and it can accept ping over LAN.

But when I try to check the sshd status, it is not work at all.
I tried to activate by:

```
systemctl start sshd
```

not work. It simply return to emergency mode and request root password.

As I need to:

```
Rebuilding initramfs
Rebuilding /etc/fstab
Rebuilding GRUB2
Rebuilding GRUB2 with LVM
```

to make the cloned disk works on new hardware by using copy and paste (It is very import). I have to use ssh to connect to the new machine.

Could any one please advise:

How to enable sshd service in emergency mode of Centos Stream 9?

Best regarding

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the following guide?

https://www.golinuxcloud.com/enable-ssh-configure-network-in-rescue-mode/

If it doesn't work - do you have any output for the command `systemctl start sshd`? Youv'e only mentioned "not work".

Comment: I tried edit rescue boot command by add "inst.sshd=1" at the end of line and then boot to rescue mode, but it always boot to emergency mode. When I tried to run [systemctl start sshd], it never give response and return to emergency mode to request root password status after a while.

Comment: And how about the last answer here? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/508374

Comment: No. The new machine never booted into rescue mode, but emergency mode.